# Лучший способ спарсить сайт с авторизацией через социальные сети

Tags: php, vkontakte-api, архитектура, парсер, facebook-api

Скажите, есть ли способ спарсить сайт с авторизацией через социальные сети лучше того, к которому я пришел.

Спарсить внешнюю часть сайта, подставить свою авторизацию, а потом используя данные входа, посылать их на нужный сайт и парсить уже материалы, кэшируя с помощью Redis на своей стороне?

Пример сайта: http://ru.heroquizz.com

Comment: Из тех, кто ставит минусы, отпишите причину хоть в комментарии.

Comment: Я пока не поставил, но, думаю, минусы за вопрос о вредоносном коде: то, что вы описываете, очень похоже на фишинговый сайт. Помогать вам красть наши данные авторизации как-то совсем уж глупо было бы.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У вас не получится подделать авторизацию через соц. сети, т.к. при авторизации, допустим, через ВКонтакте пользователя редиректит на сайт, указанный в настройках приложения (если точнее - на один из сайтов из списка "доверенных сайтов"). У ВКонтакте довольно [запутанная схема](https://vk.com/dev/auth_sites) авторизации, и вы не сможете авторизовать пользователя на чужом сайте, не отправив его на него.

Если вы просто хотите спарсить информацию, защищенную авторизацией, и если вам будет для этого достаточно одного аккаунта, то попробуйте авторизоваться через браузер, а затем скопировать полученные куки. Ну а дальше просто делайте GET-запросы к сайту, скармливая вашему cURL полученные куки. Если разработчик сайта недостаточно опытен, то такая схема будет работать.

Ну а вообще, на будущее: то, что вы делаете, не очень правильно. Делать копии сайтов с поддельной авторизацией - грех, за который можно получить по рукам, как минимум от вашего хостера. Вероятно, именно по этой причине вам и наставили минусов.